# Python Import on Apache: File not found

Tags: python, apache

I have a problem with my apache server (Shared Hosting, no root).
I've installed a python package via SSH-Terminal (with `pip install`) under `./local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`.

There is a python file which imports this package. When I run the python file via the SSH-Terminal everything works fine.
But when I run the python file within a `php exec command`

`exec("/usr/bin/python myscript.py 2>&1", $out, $result);`

an error occurs:

```
"ImportError: No module named XXX".
```

Do you know what went wrong here or what I can do to make the script work in the browser as well?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your problem is how you are importing that module. Show us that part of the python script and the location of all the files involved (the one from where you are calling the script, the script, the package, etc.)

Comment: are you sure that same python is used in php.? try `which python` cmd in terminal.

Comment: This is probably an access issue. Try installing the python package using the apache user id.

Comment: @Adirio My .py-file looks like this: 
`#!/usr/bin/env python
import jodel_api`
When I execute `python myscript.py` in ssh terminal everything works fine.
When I execute `exec("/usr/bin/python myscript.py 2>&1", $out, $result);` the import error occurs.

@onlyvinish It is located under /usr/bin/python

Comment: Take a look at Rakesh comment, it may be an access problem. Your user has access to the python site-packages folder why your apache user hasn't. onlyvinish asked you to execute `which python` both from apache and from the cmd to verify that they are the same.